# Move extension-less files with mv

Tags: command-line, files, rename, wildcards

I have a folder with images(png, bmp, jpg) and extension-less files.

I can't figure out how to move only the extension-less files. They are all random numbered files.

Answer (score 6):

With bash

```
shopt -s extglob
mv -- !(*.jpg|*.png|*.bmp) targetdir/
```

Comment: The ```!``` is to tell the command to do the opposite of what is specified?

Comment: @Dominique, `!` is an extended glob operator that matches anything other than the patterns specified, read more about it [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob)

Comment: Can I just suggest writing the target directory as `targetdir/` to guard against the case where if it doesn't exist, the source files are successively _renamed_ as `targetdir`?

Comment: @steeldriver, good point, incorporated. Feel free to edit anytime

Comment: @steeldriver, if there are several sources, `mv` won't do anything if the target isn't a directory. But you are right in that it won't work right if there is just one source

Answer (score 1):

Using the `!(...)` ksh extended glob operator for negation, so in `ksh`, `zsh -o kshglob` or `bash -O extglob`:

```
rm -- !(*.*) /dest
```

Would move the files whose name doesn't contain a dot (note that in shells other than `zsh`, if there's no such file, it  could still move the file called `!(*.*)` even though that file does contain a dot).

Using `zsh`'s `^` extended glob operator for negation, so in `zsh -o extendedglob`:

```
rm -- ^*.* /dest
```

In all the above, hidden files would not be moved, first because their name does contain a dot (they start with a dot), but also because hidden files are excluded from globs unless the glob itself starts with a literal `.`.

If you want to also move `.foo` files but not `.foo.png`, you can do:

```
mv -- ^?*.*(D) /dest # with zsh -o extended-glob

mv -- !(?*.*) /dest # with bash -O extglob -O dotglob
                    # or   zsh -o kshglob -o dotglob -o nobareglobqual
                    # or   env FIGNORE='@(.|..)' ksh93

mv -- @(.|)+([^.]) /dest # with bash -O extglob or AT&T ksh
```